# vim suspend process (while plugins still executing), screen needs refresh

Tags: shell, vim, suspend

While I'm working in vim, I often suspend the vim process with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> so I can access my bash shell. I'm on Ubuntu 14.10.

I have plugins such as syntastic loaded which take action after actions like file writes.

Something that happens all-to-frequently is that I will save a file and immediately want to do something on the shell, such as a git operation.

If I do this too fast though (save and then immediately suspend the vim process) my shell get's in a weird state where the blinking cursor is gone and half the screen needs to be repainted.

Then, when I `fg` back into the vim process it too is messed up visually and I need to redraw the screen (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>).

I understand I can "fix" the problem by forcing the redraw but any suggestions on how to avoid getting in this state?

Perhaps something like a mapping to wrap <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> and kill all plugin execution before the suspend occurs?

Comment: try vim command `:shell`?

Comment: @KevinGuan see the answer to this question on why I prefer to suspend: http://superuser.com/questions/511894/in-vim-what-are-the-differences-between-using-sus-and-sh-to-access-the-shell

Comment: I see, `<C-z>` will just  suspend the vim. but `:shell` will create a new process.

Comment: ensure your `TERM` env variable is correct for the type of terminal you are on.

Comment: echo $TERM returns "screen". I'm running lxterminal. Does that raise any flags?

Comment: But I guess you are running GNU-screen inside the lxterminal, is this correct?

Comment: No, I run Vim within tmux 99.99% of the time

Comment: You should try `TERM=xterm-color` for lxterminal.

Comment: @meuh That doesn't really seem to make a difference but that's good to know as it led me to learn a little bit about msgcat. The vim refresh problem still occurs though

Comment: Do the following tests: 1: Rename your .bashrc/.login files; 2: Check if vim works properly in a plain lxterminal (no tmux); 3: Check if vim works properly in xterm (no tmux); 4: Check if vim works properly in tmux (both in lxterminal and xterm).

Comment: @Vitor I gave a try (removed login script, tried in both lxterminal and xterm, no tmux) but still observed the same issue. It seems that vim is in the middle of an operation (probably syntastic) when this issue occurs.

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink that would make sense! Could you try calling vim with `vim -u NONE -U NONE`?

Comment: @Vitor Thanks a bunch Vitor. I now understand at least _why_ the problem is occurring. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Now you just need to pinpoint which specific plugin is responsible for that behavior and create a bug report in its github page.

Comment: @Vitor looks like this was already opened: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1068

Answer (score 1):

The first step in debugging vim is to follow the instructions in [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file).

In this particular question, the problem could also reside in the terminfo configuration. A typical example of such a problem is when `$TERM` is defined in .bashrc to a value that is not compatible with the used terminal.

Comment: This is very helpful advice, but it doesn't provide a workaround/solution to the original question.